# How to remove git commit with missing directory

Tags: git

I accidentally checked a large file into a repo on a machine that was tight on disk space. Our Sysadmin saw this and deleted the `.git` directory

`rm -rf .git/objects/51/ecbb7eb634f878f8460c55cae815c7515265bb`

I'm now getting a fatal error on push

```
$ git push origin master
Counting objects: 63, done.
error: unable to find 51ecbb7eb634f878f8460c55cae815c7515265bb
Delta compression using up to 32 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (43/43), done.
fatal: unable to read 51ecbb7eb634f878f8460c55cae815c7515265bb
error: pack-objects died with strange error
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:repo_name.git'
```

How can I just remove the `51ecbb7eb634f878f8460c55cae815c7515265bb` commit

I have un merged commits after this commit as well that I can not lose

Comment: Stupid question, but is there a way of retrieving `.git/objects/51/ecbb7eb634f878f8460c55cae815c7515265bb` from some system backup that your sysadmin may have performed before deleting it? Other question: is the undesired large file only in the last commit on the current branch, or is it part of multiple commits in the history?

Comment: @Jubobs Unfortunately no

Comment: Do you remember when you started tracking the big file? In the last commit, or before that?

Comment: looks like I started tracking it several commits ago and dumped a large amount of input to it and commited and continued from there.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to

- Remove this commit locally (`git rebase -i <commit_sha1>^` and remove the corresponding line; where `<sha1>` is the sha1 of the commit which introduce the large object)
- Delete completely the distant repo and then clone it again from your local one (using eg ssh)

Of course, you may want to make a few backups before performing such operations.

Edit: In the last step, you should not push to the remote repo (since we've deleted it, it's not possible). Instead you should clone your local repo. ie: connect to the remote server eg with ssh, and there, clone the sane repo you have on your local workstation.

Comment: Whether `51ecbb7` is a commit object is unclear, though. If the sysadmin identified `.git/objects/51/ecbb7eb634f878f8460c55cae815c7515265bb` as being too big, that's probably because that SHA identifies, not a commit object, but the blob corresponding to the large file that was committed accidentally.

Comment: It should be pretty clear: if `51ecbb7` were the commit object, it wouldn't have been the large object that caused the sysadmin to step in and delete it. :)

Comment: too be clear the sys admin `rm -rf .git/objects/51/ecbb7eb634f878f8460c55cae815c7515265bb`

Comment: @Jubobs I'm not. If the remote system is used for more than merely Git, and the lack of disk space caused real issues, and the sysadmin knows that removing the file in Git does not lead to any permanent data loss (as it will be available on other systems too), I think the sysadmin may have even made a good call.

Comment: @hvd You make a good point, but if someone deleted something in my repo's `.git` folder (without any notice)... I wouldn't like that.

Comment: @Jubobs there was notice, and like hvd pointed out there was a bit of hustle as well

Comment: Instead of deleting the remote repo could I do something like a `push -f` ?

Comment: Since the remote repo is in a corrupted state, I'm not sure it will work, but you may try.

Comment: I deleted the the remote repo and tried pushing again and I'm seeing a  similar error with : `remote: fatal: early EOF` added

Comment: you should clone, not push. I edit my answer to add this precision.